# aligning tables with different dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables, called tblDaily and tblWeekly.

So tblDaily contains daily data & tblWeekly contains data that is stored every friday.

So obviously it is easy to join the daily table to the weekly table when the date in the daily data is a friday.

My question is what is the best way to join when the date is not a friday. So for example say I had the date 2018-05-09 (Wednesday) I would like to join it on the previous friday (2018-05-04). What is the optimal way of doing this?

I read about a calendar table, would that be the correct way to go? Although I'm not sure how that would work in this case?

```
   tblDaily
   date         val
   2018-04-30   2              'mon
   2018-05-01   3              'tues
   2018-05-02   3              'wed
   2018-05-03   3              'thurs
   2018-05-04   3              'fri
   2018-05-07   2              'mon
   2018-05-08   3              'tues
   2018-05-09   3              'wed
   2018-05-10   3              'thurs
   2018-05-11   3              'fri
   2018-05-14   3              'mon

   tblWeekly
   date         val
   2018-05-04   2              'fri
   2018-05-11   3              'fri
```

Comment: You could derive the last Friday by using this query - 
`DECLARE @test_date DATETIME = '2018-05-15'
SELECT DATEADD(d,-1-(DATEPART(dw,@test_date) % 7),@test_date) AS Last_Friday`

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
SELECT
    [dailydate] = D.[date],
    [dailyval] = D.[val],
    [weeklydate] = W.[date],
    [weeklyval] = W.[val]
FROM
    [tblDaily] AS D
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP (1) _W.*
                 FROM [tblWeekly] AS _W
                 WHERE _W.[date] <= D.[date]
                 ORDER BY _W.[date] DESC) AS W;
```

This query produces the following results:

```
dailydate   dailyval  weeklydate  weeklyval
2018-04-30  2         NULL        NULL
2018-05-01  3         NULL        NULL
2018-05-02  3         NULL        NULL
2018-05-03  3         NULL        NULL
2018-05-04  3         2018-05-04  2
2018-05-07  2         2018-05-04  2
2018-05-08  3         2018-05-04  2
2018-05-09  3         2018-05-04  2
2018-05-10  3         2018-05-04  2
2018-05-11  3         2018-05-11  3
2018-05-14  3         2018-05-11  3
```

Comment: I missed the top 1

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
select * from tblDaily a join tblWeekly b on a.date1= dateadd(day,-5,b.date2)
```

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations

Comment: Just a heads up, this wouldn't provide the desired results. You aren't going to use the = operator here. They are looking for a 1 : many relation. This would skip most records in the daily table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple `join`:

```
select *
from tblDaily [d]
--first condition in join is to match firdays exactly
left join tblWeekly [w] on [w].[date] = [d].[date] or
    --here you are joining fridays from tblWeekly to last friday before the date in tblDaily
    [w].[date] = dateadd(day, -datepart(weekday, [d].[date]) - 1, [d].[date])
```

Here is [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d60bc/8).